# Powershell Or Python3 - CSV file: remove row based on duplicates in a column, with IF ELSE based conditions in another column

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, csv, duplicates, multiple-conditions

So im a bit weak in my coding and have some experience with both powershell and python so I'm open to solutions in either.

This might be hard to describe so i created a fake dataset in hopes it will make it more clear.

What im trying to do is dedupe the rows of every CSV in a directory based on name, but then in order:
If NARRATIVE="CAUGHT", i want to retain that row
else
IF NARRATIVE contains a URL, i want to retain that row
else
if neither of these are true, i want to retain the last/bottom most entry.

I feel like im closest In powershell so I'll use this example, but if you can solve this in python I'm totally open to that as well. Where am i failing here?

```
gci -Filter *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv | Foreach-Object {Select-Object where $_.NARRATIVE -Contains "Caught"} | export-csv test1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Main Data set:

```
SITE,DATE,URL,SITE2,NAME,NARRATIVE
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME1,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME2,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME3,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME4,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME5,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME6,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME7,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME1,only visited http://thisismyhouse.com once
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME2,NAME2 did some stuff and here's how/why
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME5,NAME5 just sat there
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME3,NAME3 was really important right here
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME6,NAME6 fell down and couldn’t get up
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME3,NAME3 was MOST important right here
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME8,NAME8 Dropped the beat
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME9,After the game NAME9 went home
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME4,"while NAME4 was at the store, they found a grape"
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME7,NAME7 got hit in the head
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME9,NAME9 spends a lot of time on http://dungeondepths.com
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME1,On Friday the 13th NAME1 got a tattoo
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME4,For dinner NAME4 ordered pizza
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME8,NAME8 Fired the Bass Cannon
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME9,NAME9 is rebooting
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME6 ,NAME6 broke their leg
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME8,NAME8 Put the needle on the record
```

Desired Results:

```
SITE,DATE,URL,SITE2,NAME,NARRATIVE
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME1,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME2,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME3,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME4,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME5,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME6,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME7,CAUGHT
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME9,NAME9 spends a lot of time on http://dungeondepths.com
AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME8,NAME8 Put the needle on the record
```

Comment: it looks like you could ... use `Sort-Object` on the `.Date` property, use `Group-Object` based on the `.Name` and `.Narrative` properties, and finally use `Where-Object` to filter on your three `.Narrative` values.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Well, they will always be already grouped by .Date as the date will always be the same in each csv file. Like in the example above, all of the dates are 3/17. This will always be true, so I dont know what the value is by Sort-Object on .Date.

If you've got a solution that is simpler/less code than Rogue's below Id appreciate seeing it.

Comment: Please define "*bottom most entry*". Why is `AAA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME9,NAME9 spends a lot of time on http://dungeondepths.com` considered to be a  "*bottom most entry*"?

Comment: @ScottMcCune - the `Sort-Object` step is just to be _totally curtain_ the input is in date order. if you are already _totally certain the data will always be in that order_, then skip that step. there was no way for anyone other than you to know that. [*grin*] ///// the solution by `Roque Sosa` seems to be fairly direct, so i have nothing else to offer.

Comment: @iRon the last in the list. The last entry of all entries with NAME. ```AA,03/17/2020,https://someurl.com/1234,BBB,NAME9,NAME9 spends a lot of time on http://dungeondepths.com``` is not the last most entry, but it is the correct entry because it contains a URL, condition #2.  NAME8 is the example of "bottom most entry"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I completely understand, try this (having a couple more assumptions):

```
$groupedCsv = Import-Csv .\stackTest.csv | Group-Object Name
$result = @()
foreach ($csvObject in $groupedCsv){
    if($value = $csvObject | % {$_.Group | Where-Object Narrative -eq "Caught"}){
        $result += $value
    } elseif ($value = $csvObject | % {$_.Group | Where-Object Narrative -like "*http*"}){
        $result += $value
    } else {
        $result += $csvObject.Group[-1]
    }

}

#This is just to show the result
$result | ft
```

Assumptions:

1. From each name group, only one condition will be met and I'll respect the order you gave.

With that I get your result.

I hope that fixes your problem. And if you want to run this with multiple CSVs I recommend to create this as a function and call it per CSV, to not make the logic more complicated than it needs to be, and also to be reusable, like this:

```
function Parse-Csv{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias("Path")]
        [String] $FullName
    )
    process{
        if(Test-Path -Path $FullName -IsValid){
            #SetUp
            $groupedCsv = Import-Csv -Path $FullName | Group-Object Name
            $result = @()

            #Main
            foreach ($csvObject in $groupedCsv){
                if($value = $csvObject | % {$_.Group | Where-Object Narrative -eq "Caught"}){
                    $result += $value
                } elseif ($value = $csvObject | % {$_.Group | Where-Object Narrative -like "*http*"}){
                    $result += $value
                } else {
                    $result += $csvObject.Group[-1]
                }
            }
            $result | Export-Csv -Path $FullName -Force -NoTypeInformation
        } else{
            Write-Error "Invalid path provided ($Path), please verify and try again."
        }
    }
}

gci -Filter *.csv | Parse-Csv
```

Comment: So in regards to NAME1, the row with Narrative = "only visited http://thisismyhouse.com once" should not be included because NAME1 also has a NARRATIVE = "Caught". I only want 1 of each NAME. 

In regards to your assumptions:

1. All URLS will have https:// so really we can just do another Where-Object {($_.NARRATIVE -contains "https:")
2. If i understand what you're saying here you're correct. Example:
NAME8,NAME8 Dropped the beat
NAME8,NAME8 Fired the Bass Cannon
NAME8,NAME8 Put the needle on the record

of all instances of NAME8, none are "CAUGHT" and none have a URL, so keep last

Comment: Ok, I didnt catch from your description that name had anything to do with what you needed, I modified it, now it should work, I followed  Lee_Dailey advice.

Comment: if it worked, would you mind marking it as the answer?

Comment: _"What im trying to do is dedupe the rows of every CSV in a directory based on name"_ - sorry i neglected to capitalize NAME in the first sentence.

So i saved the function as a .ps1 and would then call it like: ```gci -Filter *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv | % {.\Parse-Csv $_}``` correct? I'm not seeming to be able to get that to work. Additionally, i dont think i mentioned before that I'm seeking it to overwrite each original file in the directory with the new, deduped' data.

Comment: I'm not seeming to be able to get that to work, nor was i able to get it to work without having it as a .ps1 as I'm not sure where to put the function if to call it in a single line of cmdlets. I think ideally, id save it as a .psm1 module with ```Export-ModuleMember -Function Parse-Csv``` at the end so i can just import the module and make a clean one line

Comment: if you want to use it as a function, create a ps1 with only the function, run it, and then you'll be able to use it only in that powershell instance, if you want to have it available always add it to you powershell profile (`New-Item $profile -itemtype File ; ise $profile` and restart powershell).

Comment: i'm able to get it to return $result but i'm not able to get it to overwrite each file in the directory with the new data. I'm seeking to avoid creating new files on the export.

Comment: ok, no problem, let's do this, select it as answer and I'll add how you can replace current csvs.

Comment: There we go. Done.

Comment: great, give it a go, let me know how it goes.

Comment: well it, *kind of* works. It definitely removed some but i still have multiples of some entries left when applying it to my real dataset, when i should only have 1 of any given name. And i double checked, they are spelled the same, and i removed leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: OH I see the problem, it doesnt just take the first (or any 1) entry with a url ("http") it keeps ALL entries with a URL. Interesting, because it handled the "Caught" properly, where it took the first and discarded any entries that weren't "Caught"

Comment: Exactly it'll add all items that make this expressions `$true`, `Where-Object Narrative -eq "Caught"` and `Where-Object Narrative -like "*http*"` but as its processed by name you will never have more that 1 condition met by name. If you want to have only 1 item pass by criteria, you can add `select -Last 1` to the end of those pipelines (continuing the assumption that the lists are ordered).